# Can I block search engines from scanning files starting with a certain letter using robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I know I can block search engines from accessing types of files using a wild card like this:

```
Disallow: /*.gif$
```

That disallows access to gifs, or more like files ending in .gif.

But is there a way to prevent search engines from accessing for example all files starting with "_"?

Would something like this work?

```
Disallow: /_*.*$
```

Or at least perhaps this (if I absolutely need to set an extension)?

```
Disallow: /_*.php$
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the "official" [docs](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

> Note also that globbing and regular expression are **not** supported in either the User-agent or Disallow lines.

Comment: According to this:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596
...you can exclude filetypes using that wildcard I mentioned in the question (code quoted from same page). So even if officially that won't work, it does work with Google. That probably means I can't have an objective answer though (I wasn't aware different search engines parse robots.txt differently).